# How to link Number value with Field calculator in QGIS Modeler ?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, algorithm, qgis-modeler

I want to link 2 number values (RMSE & dosemax) in a field calculator formula. When I run the modeler, I add these values but it doesn't recognize them. I dont want to create a new table. Just use these number in the formula.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't do this directly using the number parameters. You will need to create a **custom script** which reads those number values, inserts them into a string expression, and finally outputs the expression as a string parameter which can then be fed into the Field Calculator tool.

Comment: I starts to be hard for me to follow. Do you have a picture of where i can do this script ?

Answer (score 1):

To create a **custom script**, you can go to the `Processing Toolbox > Scripts > Tools > Create new script` and use something like the following (change the expression accordingly, you do not need to add quotes around the number parameters):

```
##Example=name
##dosemax=number
##RMSE=number
##expression=output string

dose = str(dosemax)
rmse = str(RMSE)
expression = 'if("moyennemea" < minumum("moyennemea")+3*rmse, 0.75*dose, dose)'
```

Save the script into your `/.qgis2/processing/scripts` directory. Then add the script to your model selecting the input number parameters for the script:

[image: Script parameters]

Then in the **Field Calculator** tool, select the script for the expression:

[image: Field calculator]

The expression should now use the number values from the parameters.